# android.mk sdl building errors

Tags: android, c++, c, android.mk

I've looked around at some questions about writing android.mk files and the **"make: *** No rule to make target .c needed by .o"** they all center around typos which I don't think that I have.

This is an SDL project that builds fine with my CMake build scripts but I just can't get android.mk to work for me.

Here's the project setup in cmake

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(blp)
#set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)

FIND_PACKAGE(SDL2 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/core_math")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/utils/time_utils")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/utils/resource_utils")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/ren_opengl")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/core_engine")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/components/renderable2d")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/glm/vec3.hpp")

FIND_PACKAGE(SDL2 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

FIND_PACKAGE(SDL2_IMAGE)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(source)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(project)

SET(SRC_FILES main.c)
SET(EXTERNAL_TARGET_LIBS ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY})
SET(COMPONENTS renderable2d)
SET(INTERNAL_TARGET_LIBS core_math time_utils resource_utils ren_opengl)

SET(TARGET_LIBS ${INTERNAL_TARGET_LIBS} ${EXTERNAL_TARGET_LIBS} ${COMPONENTS})

FILE(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/resources/)
```

the project subfolder is where I can create different projects and reuse the source dynamic libs that I create.

inside the source, you can see I have a bunch of dynamic libs that are created. At the end there's the dynamic libs and one .h and .c class that imports all of them, then I import that one .h file inside my project to use the libs.

Now onto my android.mk file, it's not very complete yet but this is where I am running into trouble.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/utils/time_utils/

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
                 utils/time_utils.c \
//removing the above line, core_engine.c throws an import error
//adding the above line I get the error listed at the bottom
                 core_engine/core_engine.c \
                 project.c


LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/blubee/SDL/android-project/jni/src/time_utils/time_utils.c', needed by `/Users/blubee/SDL/android-project/obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/time_utils/time_utils.o'.  Stop.
```

each lib is under it's own folder int he project source tree like this

```
source/components/renderable2d/renderable2d.c /.h
source/core_engine/core_engine.c /.h
source/core_math/mat4_scalar/mat4_scalar.c /.h
source/core_math/vec3_scalar/vec3_scalar.c /.h
source/..
etc...
```

It could be a build oder or the order in which I am defining the sources files in the android.mk folder, I am not sure. Any suggestions? I also made sure that there's no typos or extra spaces in my environment variables or the source file for the android.mk

Comment: Where are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that android.mk is a lot more sensitive to header include order more so than cmake.

I simplified my project just to a main.c with a #include "SDL.h" and that builds just fine.

I will go from there and learn android.mk, while it's similar to cmake it's a lot more picky.